# Refresh Notification from PBI report server

Tags: notifications, powerbi, refresh

I am trying to set up refresh notification ( failed reports) from a PBI report server.
As a admin of PBI report server, I want to be notified for all reports in report server that failed to refresh.

I see there is an option to "Send Refresh notification" to configure from PowerBI desktop (personal workspace) but I am do not see any option from PBI report server.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option for auto notification for this matter in PBIRS.
But you can use this sql code in your sql agent job:

```
USE PBIRS;

DECLARE @MAIL_BODY VARCHAR(8000);

/* HEADER */

SET @MAIL_BODY =
'<table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="color:black;font-family:consolas;text-align:center;">'
+ '<tr>
    <th>Dashboard Name</th>
    <th>Refresh Status</th>

    </tr>';

/* ROWS */

SELECT @MAIL_BODY = @MAIL_BODY + '<tr>' + '<td>' + [c].[Name] + '</td>' +
'<td>' + [LastStatus] + '</td>' + '</tr>'
FROM   [PBIRS].[dbo].[Subscriptions] [s]
       LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Catalog] [c] ON [s].[Report_OID] = [c].[ItemID];

SELECT @MAIL_BODY = @MAIL_BODY + '</table>';

IF
(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   [PBIRS].[dbo].[Subscriptions] [s]
           LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Catalog] [c] ON [s].[Report_OID] = [c].
           [ItemID]
    WHERE  [LastStatus] NOT IN('Completed Data Refresh')
) != 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail] 
             @profile_name = 'profile_name', 
             @recipients = 'your_email_address', 
             @subject =
             '[The Refresh failed.] These dashboards Faild to Refresh successfully', 
             @body = @MAIL_BODY, 
             @body_format = 'HTML';
    END;
```

Replace profile_name with email profile in your instance and your_email_address with any email you want.

What does this code do?
It checks which dashboard failed to refresh successfully and send the list by email. The output would be like this:

[Email Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMBmL.png)

Comment: You might mention that there is NO auto notifications in the RS version.

Comment: Your'e right. I edited the answer.

Answer (score -1):

- To enable this settings, go to PowerBI service and then under your dataset select on "**Scheduled refresh**" settings by clicking on the Ellipsis button next to it
- In the new page of dataset settings, collapse Scheduled refresh and enable "Send refresh failure notifications to the dataset owner"
- You can also add other users if you would like with their emails.

[Sample settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJhuy.png)

Comment: This answer explain how to do this in Power BI Service, while the question is about Power BI Report Server (the on-premise version of Power BI).

Comment: Thank you for response. I am still wondering if this is applicable for all reports published in Power Bi Report server ? I have seen the option ""Scheduled refresh" " when I login to "https://app.powerbi.com/home" and I see only my workspace here.  My question is As an admin, I want to set notification for all reports published in PowerBI Report Server. Let me know if my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: Hi @rsyas, my apologies I misread the server as service. Unfortunately there is no option for alerts in Power BI server as far as I know. Although the idea was put forward to MS, it has not been planned. Reference: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/19799476-email-subscriptions-for-power-bi-reports-in-report

Comment: Thanks you @BVee. For now, I wrote a simple query to error messages from ReportServer database tables and sending database emails. ! Thanks for help.